# Leaf-curling type spider southeastern US

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I have a spider in my backyard in Mobile, AL.  It seems to have sewn itself up inside of a living water oak leaf.  I tried googling it but only came up with [this Austrailian spider](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonognatha_graeffei) that does a similar thing, but not exactly.  Notably, there is no attendant web, just the folded leaf container.  The leaf has been folded twice into a perfect little tetrahedral home.  Here is a picture... I didn't want to disturb her too much:

[image]

What species is this beautiful geometer?

Comment: Scott, please try to get another image of the spider -- one in which we can actually see the spider :p. Thanks

Comment: I would expect this to be an orbweaver, as I've seen numerous examples of leaf shelters for these spiders.  Usually, they're associated with a big orbweb, though.  It's not going to be anything with an unpleasant bite, though, so it should be fine to gently open up (maybe have a bowl underneath to catch the spider when she drops out) and expose the occupant for a photo.